# Updating a d3.js choropleth / table combo using an html dropdown

Tags: csv, dictionary, d3.js, dropdown, choropleth

Good evening Stackoverflow,

Long time reader, first time asking.

My early searches took me to this bl.ock http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7557092

Very cool indeed. So, I took that code and went to work. I have got it working as you can see at the example below.

I have placed everything in a fiddle for you. jsfiddle.net/Majomo/npya9khq/

Also, I was warned by a red box to post the code here. Has made my post massive but the red box made me do it and wouldn't take no for an answer. Sorry for the wall of text.

the html

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.9.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>

    <body>
      <!-- Table to hold the Divs -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="10" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="table_container" class="csvTable"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="map_container"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="d3legend" class="legend"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="styled-select">
              <select id="data_sources" name="data_sources">
                <option value="regionalDistrictData.csv" selected>Census 1996 Data</option>
                <option value="regionalDistrictData2.csv">Census 2001 Data</option>
                <option value="regionalDistrictData3.csv">Census 2006</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</html>
```

the css

```
rect {
  fill: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature {
  fill: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mesh {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.csvTable table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.csvTable {
  font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #069;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.csvTable table td,
.csvTable table th {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.csvTable table thead th {
  background: 0;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');
  background-color: #006D2C;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-left: 1px solid #0070A8;
}

.csvTable table thead th:first-child {
  border: none;
}

.csvTable table tbody td {
  color: #00496B;
  border-left: 1px solid #E1EEF4;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1EEF4;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.csvTable table tbody td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.csvTable table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.csvTable tr:hover td {
  background-color: #069;
  color: white;
}

.styled-select select {
  background: transparent;
  font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 268px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.styled-select {
  width: 240px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/2e3ybe1.jpg) no-repeat right #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #069;
}
```

the js

```
 // Based on http://public.johnnyotoole.fastmail.fm/county_map.html
 // Based on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541

 //Width and height
 var w = 600;
 var h = 750;
 var active;
 var jsonOutside;

 //Define map projection NB change to albers and changed zoom etc
 var projection = d3.geo.albers()
   .center([-3.5, 43.4])
   .rotate([121, -11])
   .scale(2400)
   .translate([w / 2, h / 2]);

 //Define path generator
 var path = d3.geo.path()
   .projection(projection);

 //Create SVG element
 var svg = d3.select("#map_container")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);

 // from colorbrewer (http://colorbrewer2.org/)
 //var colours = ["#BAE4B3", "#74C476", "#31A354", "#006D2C"];
 //var colours = ["#fef0d9", "#fdcc8a", "#fc8d59", "#d7301f"];

 // setup colours for choropleth
 var colScale = d3.scale.quantile()
   .domain([1.2, 1.5, 2])
   .range(['#edf8fb', '#b3cde3', '#8c96c6', '#8856a7', '#810f7c']);


 var dropdown = d3.select("#data_sources")
 var change = function() {
   var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;
   d3.csv(source, function(csv) {
     //continue doing stuff here.
   })
 }

 dropdown.on("change", change)
 change(); //trigger json on load

 svg.append("rect")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h)
   .on("click", reset);

 var g = svg.append("g");


 //Load in CSV data
 d3.csv(src = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/majomo/2d5409622ff825ad932d/raw/5a37026b6c11d129a6eb1bcd32ef2a23d8833770/regDistBC.csv", function(data) {

   //Load in GeoJSON data
   d3.json(src = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/majomo/1beba4e212d12f3d6e29/raw/1bd280591bc4959449505395c90f7ffdd2e2ddbd/bcGeo.json", function(json) {

     // join csv data with json data and create
     json.features.forEach(function(d, i) {
       data.forEach(function(e, j) {
         if (d.properties.CDNAME === e.Region) {
           d.properties.value = +e.Result;
         };
       })
     })

     jsonOutside = json; // pass json to a global so tableRowClicked has access

     var columns = ["Region", "Result"];
     var table = d3.select("#table_container").append("table"),
       thead = table.append("thead"),
       tbody = table.append("tbody");

     // append the header row
     thead.append("tr")
       .selectAll("th")
       .data(columns)
       .enter()
       .append("th")
       .text(function(column) {
         return column;
       });

     // create a row for each object in the data
     var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("tr");

     // create a cell in each row for each column
     var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
       .data(function(row) {
         return columns.map(function(column) {
           return {
             column: column,
             value: row[column]
           };
         });
       })
       .enter()
       .append("td")
       .text(function(d) {
         return d.value;
       })
       .on("click", function(d) {
         tableRowClicked(d);
       }); // added on click eventto td         element NB you need to click on the cell with the conuty name

     // add extents (max and min) from data results for choropleth
     colScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
       return d.Result;
     }));

     //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
     g.selectAll("path")
       .data(json.features)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("d", path)
       .attr("class", "feature")
       .attr("id", function(d) {
         return d.properties.CDNAME;
       }) // added id so click could work on id which is common between the json and csv data
       .on("click", function(d) {
         click(d);
       })
       .style("stroke", "gray")
       .style("fill", function(d, i) {
         return colScale(d.properties.value);
       }); // fill based on colour scale

     g.append("path")
       .data(json.features)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("class", "mesh")
       .attr("d", path);
   });

 });

 function click(d) {

   if (active === d) return reset();
   g.selectAll(".active").classed("active", false);
   d3.select("#" + d.properties.CDNAME).classed("active", active = d); // changed selection to id

   var b = path.bounds(d);

   g.transition().duration(750).attr("transform",
     "translate(" + projection.translate() + ")" + "scale(" + .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / w, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / h) + ")" + "translate(" + -(b[1][0] + b[0][0]) / 2 + "," + -(b[1][1] + b[0][1]) / 2 + ")");
 }

 function reset() {
   g.selectAll(".active").classed("active", active = false);
   g.transition().duration(750).attr("transform", "");
 }

 function tableRowClicked(x) {

   jsonOutside.features.forEach(function(d) { // loop through json data to match td entry
     if (x.value === d.properties.CDNAME) {
       var region = d;
       click(d); // pass json element that matches td data to click
     };
   })
 };
```

So far, it looks great but I am now getting lost.

As you can see, I created an html dropdown that I would like to use to control what data set gets loaded. I have searched and found answers that have got me to this point. I have 3 csv files with different data and am trying to use the dropdown to select each one. 
The answers / websites I was studying all advised some variant of this.

```
var dropdown = d3.select("#data_sources")
var change = function() {
  var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;
  d3.csv(source, function(csv) {
     //continue doing stuff here.
  })
}

dropdown.on("change", change)
change(); //trigger json on load
```

My issue is that when I tried this, I was getting nowhere. I removed it from my code above as I am not even sure when it belongs anymore. My big concern it that there is a table and a map and I do not know where to get to work.

So, with all that said, I am wondering, 
is this method possible for what I want to achieve? 
If not, is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance for any direction you might offer.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change the data source of your graph, you need to be able to separate the initialization phase, that will build and draw the elements of the charts that are common to all data sources, and the actual drawing on the elements that depend on you data. Here it looks like all your charts will have a lot in common as you will be visualizing different values for the same geo regions.

Once you've done that, the code for all the common stuff only needs to be run once, you can put the rest in a function that takes the data as an argument. Every time you want to refresh the data source, you just call this function with the new data!

I modified your jsfiddle a little to show you how this could work for your case. It's really not the optimal solution but this should give you an idea about the structure of the code. As you can see I chose to delete everything from the svg and the table everytime and redraw everything. Your final updateChart function could be much smarter that that, in your case, if the regions stay the same, updateChart only needs to update the paths' colors and the table cell's inner  text.

jsfiddle.net/jwd2ded9/7/